# How to set a font in rich edit 4?

Tags: c++, winapi, richedit

I want to change the font of the richedit control in my win32 program to Consolas. When i try to do the following:

```
CHARFORMAT2 cformat;
cformat.dwMask = CFM_FACE;
cformat.cbSize = sizeof(cformat);
cformat.szFaceName = "Consolas";
```

On the last line it says that

> Expression must be  modifiable value

What is the problem here?

Regards,

Devjeet

Comment: Is it not working as expected or giving errors? Where is your SendMessage call with EM_SETCHARFORMAT ?

Comment: it is giving errors. The last line in that piece of code generates a build error

Comment: I can't tell whats going on from what you have asked. Maybe the whole/all error message(s) would be helpful. More code couldn't hurt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787883%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you can see that `szFaceName` is an array. You cannot assign to an array that way. (That's what the compiler is trying to tell you. You're trying to assign "Consolas" to something that cannot be modified in that way.) You need to use a string copy function.